# How to use Mockito with dexmaker for Android Testing?

Tags: android, mockito, dexmaker

I am trying to get Mockito (1.9.5 rc1) working in my Android tests (using Robotium). For making it run on the DVM I put dexmaker.jar and the dexmaker-mockito.jar (v 0.9) in the classpath of the test-project.

When run following test as an Android JUnit test in Eclipse:

```
package com.stampay.pos.test;

import roboguice.RoboGuice;
import android.app.Application;

import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;
import com.stampay.pos.activities.HomeActivity;
import com.stampay.pos.model.Consumer;
import com.stampay.pos.util.ScannerAndroid;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class HomeActivityTest extends ActivityTest<HomeActivity> {
    private Solo solo;
    Application app;

    public HomeActivityTest() {
        super(HomeActivity.class);

    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
        RoboGuice.util.reset();
    }

    public void testScan() throws Exception {

        ScannerAndroid scanner = (ScannerAndroid) getActivity().getScannerHelper();

        Consumer mockConsumer = mock(Consumer.class);

        //scanner.generateResult("consumer1");
    }
}
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.stampay.pos.test.HomeActivityTest.testScan(HomeActivityTest.java:41)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.<init>(MockitoCore.java:40)
at org.mockito.Mockito.<clinit>(Mockito.java:932)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<clinit>(MockUtil.java:21)
... 17 more
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MockitoConfigurationException: Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker using jar:file:/data/app/com.stampay.pos.test-2.apk!/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.dexmaker.mockito.DexmakerMockMaker
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.loadImplementations(ClassPathLoader.java:133)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.findPlatformMockMaker(ClassPathLoader.java:102)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.<clinit>(ClassPathLoader.java:61)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<clinit>(MockUtil.java:21)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.<init>(MockitoCore.java:40)
at org.mockito.Mockito.<clinit>(Mockito.java:932)
... 15 more
```

Any suggestions? http://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/ and http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/ReleaseNotes do not provide any helpful information.

A similar problem seems to be reported here: http://www.paulbutcher.com/2012/05/mockito-on-android-step-by-step/#comment-65955

UPDATE:
with the .jar files from https://github.com/paulbutcher/mockito-on-android/tree/master/WarehouseManagerTest/libs all works smoothly, though he uses an outdated snapshot of Mockito based on 1.9.1

Comment: I have the same issue happening, I'm using Maven include the dependencies, but I have the exact same error being raised that it can't find the com.google.dexmaker.mockito.DexmakerMockMaker class.

Comment: Also, I've looked into it being removed by ProGuard, but I have tried explicitly keeping the DexmakerMockMaker class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem attempting to use mockito 1.9.5-rc1.

The dexmaker page [notes that you need 1.9.5+](http://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/) for this, and apparently RC1 doesn't cut it. [Mockito 1.9.5 appears to have just been released days ago](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/ReleaseNotes), so it should show up shortly in Maven Central.

In the meantime, you can [download the 1.9.5 zip from Mockito's site](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/downloads/list). If you're using Maven, you could manually install those jars to your local repo with `mvn install:install-file`. I also got this to work by checking out the latest Mockito source (unreleased 1.9.8), building, and installing to my local Maven repo.